# need to determine the positive, negative and zero numbers in program and add all the positive and negative numbers separately

Tags: java

I need to determine the positive, negative and zero numbers in  a program and add all the positive and negative numbers separately. I'm using while loop (can use do-while) because for loop and array is not allowed. Badly need your help. Here's my code. The code should allow entering 10 numbers before determining.

```
public class Mix22 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ety = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count=0;
        int positive=0;
        int negative =0;
        int num=0;


        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        num = ety.nextInt();

        while(num!=10){

            if(num<0)
                negative++;

            if (num>0)
                positive++;

            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            num = ety.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Negative numbers in the program: " + negative);
        System.out.println("Positive numbers in the program: " + positive);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Telling what the problem is is half of the solution to fix it. And we shouldn't  have to guess. You should test your code and tell us what it is.

Comment: You haven’t asked a question and from looking at the code you haven’t spent much time on your assignment so this looks like a request for us to do your homework

Comment: I just need help to figure it out dude. It's not a request to do a homework or anything. It's just I have troubles figuring it out. That's why I'm asking. Sorry to bother you though.

Comment: the problem is I'm having a hard time determining zeros and the sum of negative numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: You have if < 0, and if < 0 ... what about if == 0?!

Comment: here the condition I'm trying to use

Comment: while(num<10){
        if(num<0) {
     negativeSum+=num;
  
 if (num>0)
     positiveSum+=num;
 
 if (num==0) 
     zero++;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that you want to run the loop 10 times? You've got a `count` variable that you are not otherwise using. The loop should look something like:

```
int count=0;
while (count != 10) {
    ...
    ++count;
}
```

Conventionally a `for` loop is used for this (if allowed):

```
for (int count=0; count<10; ++count) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, and the output should determine the positive numbers, negative numbers, zeros, sum of positive numbers, sum of negative numbers. Unfortunately, only allowed to use while and do-while loop. Array is also not allowed.

Comment: @Saxton So use the `while` loop code. Sum with `int positiveSum = 0;` ... `if (num > 0) { positiveSum += num; }`.

Comment: Thank you @Tom Hawtin :) much appreciated!